# Set up an AWS alert to send a message if one of a set of instances is running longer than X hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops

At work we have two different types of EC2 instances on Amazon Web Services (AWS). A set of them that get turned on during work hours and off at night. Another set (used for demos and the like) that are turned on and off on demand. We can't really predict whether these will be on or off but it would be unusual if they run for longer than 24 hours.

To save money, I want to have an alert be triggered if any of a certain set of instances (perhaps marked by having a certain tag or custom property) run for longer than 24 hours, so we can investigate and turn them off it was by mistake.

There's two sides to this:

1. How can I create an alert for a group of instances?
2. How can I detect that an instance has been running for X amount of time (I'm thinking perhaps an alert like: `CPU_UTILIZATION > 0` might work?)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this task is for Lambda:

- use `aws ec2 describe-instances` equivalent using lambda to get Launchtime
- lambda function crawl across those metrics. If any instance runs longer than needed then the same lambda function can stop it.
- profit! :)